# Overriding QLabel to be able to draw graphs

Tags: qt, qpainter, qlabel

I want to draw a graph on my main form, so I figured I'd use a QLabel and Override that.  Like this:

```
// drawlabel.h
class DrawLabel : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        DrawLabel(QWidget *parent = 0);
    private:
        void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *);
};

// drawlabel.cpp
DrawLabel::DrawLabel(QWidget *parent)
    : QLabel(parent)
{
}

void DrawLabel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    qDebug() << "paint event" ;

    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setPen(QPen(QBrush(QColor(0,0,0,180)),1,Qt::DashLine));

    painter.setBrush(QBrush(QColor(255,255,255,120)));

    QRect selectionRect(10, 10, 100, 101);

    painter.drawRect(selectionRect);
}
```

On my main window I droppde a QLabel, sized it to about 500x200 and promoted it to DrawLLabel.  When the application is run, a dashed square is drawn on the form.

All good so far.

If I add the line:
    this->setText("123456");

into the DrawLabel constructor, or add it into the paintEvent() I don't see the text.  I'd also like to be able to have a border around the DrawLabel, but

```
this->setFrameShape(QFrame::Box);
```

in the constructor doesn't work either.

What should I be doing to get these to work?

Comment: One advice: add 'override' to the declaration of 'paintevent'. It is useful in case that you might misspell it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think you should call `paintEvent`  of base class. Add parameter name `e` to method:

```
void DrawLabel::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *e)
```

And then at end of method add

```
QLabel::paintEvent (e);
```

The second option do all painting by yourself directly at `paintEvent`.

Comment: That seems to be working - at least for the text.  Setting a border doesn't seem to work, though :(    Thanks for your help.

Comment: Then you should drow border by yourself. Pleas, mark my answer as valid.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something custom, then implement a custom widget inheriting `QWidget`. Then you get to draw whatever you want and have whatever members you want.

Your problem is you have overridden the label's paint event, so the code to draw the label text is not executed.

You could call the method from `QLabel` as Evgeny suggested, but it is better to implement a custom widget instead.

Calling the method from the base class *might* for example corrupt any previous drawing, unless the method was implemented with calling form derived classes in mind. I don't expect that is the case for stock widgets. I haven't tried doing it with `QLabel` re-implementations in particular, but I have tried it with other stock widgets and it did not work as expected.

Comment: Thanks, @ddriver.  I'll have to look into a fully custom widget.  By using a QLabel, I was hoping to get lots of goodies already implemented.  Thanks again.